# Panel visibility not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a simple login page with 2 panels. Panel for login where user enters user name and password. I validate if username is present and do this:

```
string query = "SELECT UserName,HashedPassword,SaltString FROM users WHERE UserName='"+txtUserName.Text+"'";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (!sdr.Read())
{
pnlLogin.Visible = false;
pnlRegister.Visible = true;
}
else
{
//validate password and redirect
}
```

I remember to have done same thing a few times before, although I don't have the code with me. I use form authentication in web.config. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

And one if I comment this:

```
pnlLogin.Visible = false;
```

the pnlRegister becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

If pnlRegister is nested in (a child of) pnlLogin, and you hide pnlLogin, pnlRegister will also be invisible.

Since you didn't provide markup, this is a  guess based on the behavior you described.

Comment: That was very silly of me. I didn't think about it at all. Thanks a lot sir